# Web page not responsive even with use of Bootstrap and not using px

Tags: html, css, resolution, mobile-website

I understand that this question has been asked countless amounts of times, however I still haven't found a working response!

**Here is the site on my resolution (1440 x 900):**

[image: Website in question on 1440x900 resolution.]

**And here is the site on a friend's resolution (1920 x 1080):**

https://gyazo.com/7bbdd9dd9119059f1ca65c034560abc6

I can't seem to understand why this is happening! I have literally tried everything. I've tried vw and vh, percentages as well as bootstrap stuff and to no avail at all.

**HTML Code:**

```
  <div class="form-control" style="background-color: transparent;border-style: none;">
<form class="loginform" action="loginprocess.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="labels" for="uname">Username</label>
    <input class="usernameinput" type="text" name="username" id="uname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="labels" for="pwd">Password</label>
    <input class="passwordinput" type="password" name="password" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="image" class="loginbutton" src="assets/img/login.png" onclick="PlaySound()">
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.backbutton {

position:relative;
left:1%;
top:1%;
width:2%;
height:4%;
opacity:0.5;

}

.loginform {

position:relative;
left: 40vw;
top:33vh;
width:25vw;


}

input[type=text] {

width: 28.7vw;

}

input[type=password] {

width: 28.7vw;

}

.loginbutton {

position:relative;
left:19.25vw;
top:1vh;
max-width: 40%;
height: 35%;

}

.labels {

color:white;
position:relative;
left: -11vw;
top: 6vh;
font-family: 'Chakra Petch', sans-serif;
font-size: 200%;

}
```

Thank you so much for reading! I hope someone can help me out with this :)

Comment: Not really sure of your question but one thing I have noticed is that you have not closed off `<div class="form-control" style="background-color: transparent;border-style: none;">`. It may just be from when you copied the code into the question. Maybe if you could elaborate on the question? Cheers

Comment: Could you give the link to the site?

Comment: `form-control` is a class that's only intended to be be used on, well, form controls; that is, input and select elements. You probably want to start with removing that class.

Comment: try bootstrap grids , row and col classes

Comment: @ShireeshaParampalli I haven't been able to really understand the row and col classes as of yet sadly

Comment: @TiesonT. Oh! My bad, thank you

Comment: @Darren Yeah, I had put a closing /div tag but apparently I forgot to include it in the snippet in my post, apologies

Answer (score 0):

If it is that you want the login form to remain in the middle, both vertically and horizontally for any screen.

You could surround the `form` with a container and apply

```
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
```

Here is a snippet, although if you are using Bootstrap then you may want to look at their use of `jumbotron` as seen here [jumbotron](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/jumbotron/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: blue !important;
}

form {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-group {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.form-group:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

label {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  min-width: 90px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=image] {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <form class="loginform" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="uname">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="uname">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="pwd">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/login-button-png-13.png">
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I attempted to use this, but it still didn't happen to work. We have now, however done the login page in another way... But could I have some help with in the future pages? The page im working on now... The sizing is fine, but the positioning is off... The div is way to the right for the bigger resolution, and using vw and % hasn't seemed to work sadly. I attempted using media queries, but it didn't change at all.